# spring configuration not autowired before bean creation?

Tags: java, spring

So one of my configuration classes includes both (Testing/Production)DatabaseConfig classes, and the right one gets chosen by the the active profile. But when the DatabaseConfig class runs, it's dataSource ivar is null.

I did a debug, my TestingDatabaseConfig's dataSource() method is run before DatabaseConfig's localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() is run.

I guess my question is, why isn't this working, should it work, and what am I doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"testing-db", "production-db"})
@Import({TestingDatabaseConfig.class, ProductionDatabaseConfig.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig
{
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);

        // other config

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    // ... other db related beans stuff ...
}

@Configuration
@Profile("testing-db")
public class TestingDatabaseConfig implements DatabaseConfigInterface
{
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        JDBCDataSource dataSource = new JDBCDataSource();
        dataSource.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testing");
        dataSource.setUser("sa");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course they're not injected before the call to the constructor.

Use [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). Here's a nice example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/

Comment: I'm not sure how you think that is going to help. First, the constructor has nothing to do with it as far as I can tell, it is that my DatbaseConfig class is created but not autowired before the beans are created.


Secondly, the order of construction is how I'd expect and then want it. DatabaseConfig (constructor run) -> TestingDatabaseConfig (constructor run) -> TestingDatabaseConfig (dataSource bean created) -> DatabaseConfig (emf bean created)


The problem is that I don't have access to the dataSource bean when creating my emf bean.

Comment: @dustins : If you want to put any initialization code to in your bean which requires an autowired field you have to create a method and annotate it with `@PostConstruct` and do the initialization there. The reason is simple: all your autowired fields are `null` while in the constructor. (Except of course for constructor based injection, but that's a different story) The `@PostConstruct` annotated method will be called by spring __after__ injection, but __before__ the bean will be used in the framework.

Comment: I get that, but I'm not—and wasn't doing anything inside of the constructor. I don't even have a constructor. I don't see how putting @PostConstruct on anything will help, my bean methods are already running after the constructor. I'm sure I'm just not understanding what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @dustins : At `entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);` in the constructor, your dataSource is null (not yet injected) unless you do constructor based injection. That was all I wanted to communicate, but it seems I failed miserably :) Anyways, I'm happy that you just found a solution :)

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi - Where do you see anything running in a constructor ?the code you point to, entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource, is not ran inside constructor, but inside a bean creation method 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'. The ds is not autowired, but not just yet, it's context creation order dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I must have just done this wrong the first time, but the solution is to let the beans be autowired as parameters instead of trying to have them injected as an ivar. A fake diff of what I had to change to get it to work…

```
-    @Resource
-    private DataSource dataSource;

- public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
+ public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource)

-    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
+    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Ended up being cleaner than what I was trying to do anyways =)

Comment: The first version was also ok, but with this (constructor based injection) you just used a different 'style'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that things do not just magically work! If you want configuration classes to have their ivars autowired, you have to have it configured correctly, or in this case, having another bean that does the autowiring.

You need to create the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean.

```
@Bean
public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor autowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()
{
    return new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

or

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be to put a `@ComponentScan(basePackages=..)` on your @Configuration classes, this will by default register a AutoWiredAnnotationBeanProcessor